# urdf collada difference

Tags: ros, joint, urdf, collada, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
What is the major difference of urdf,stl,collada?
STL is only composed by mesh, so it only can move the whole object, right?
And urdf can define several joints to move.
But if I use collada file could I move joints like importing urdf?
Or I should import many collada files and control each part separately?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9312/urdf-collada-difference/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Collada](http://https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_-_Digital_Asset_and_FX_Exchange_Schema) spec. 1.5 allows you to include also the kinematic chains. On the last Beta Program Conference Call I remembered one group (I think JSK) was expanding the Collada-ROS implementation. I currently have no idea of the current status.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_model natively support collada file, you can export collada format from existing urdf(http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf) and display it in rviz (http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf/Tutorials/Working%20Directly%20with%20COLLADA). One benefit of using collada is you can add your own information as a part of collada tag.

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1